# Stuck with image import using magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport

I m importing Magento products with a native Magento import profile. All the products were imported successfully but the image is not imported. I have also put the images on media/import folder and in csv write the image name like /image1.jpg but it still gives a null image after successfully importing csv.

what will be the issue please help

Comment: just go throught this link [Go To This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015410/stuck-with-image-import-using-magento-1-9-2-1/34036388#34036388)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your import file? This will help solve the problem.